# Python: argument parser that handles global options to sub-commands properly

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments, argparse, subcommand

argparse fails at dealing with sub-commands receiving global options:

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--arg', action='store_true')
s = p.add_subparsers()
s.add_parser('test')
```

will have `p.parse_args('--arg test'.split())` work,
but fails on `p.parse_args('test --arg'.split())`.

Anyone aware of a python argument parser that handles global options to sub-commands properly?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails'? What do you want to happen? What global options?

Comment: fail as in complaining about the unknown argument --arg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Give docopt a try](http://docopt.org):

```
>>> from docopt import docopt

>>> usage = """
... usage: prog.py command [--test]
...        prog.py another [--test]
... 
... --test  Perform the test."""

>>> docopt(usage, argv='command --test')
{'--test': True,
 'another': False,
 'command': True}

>>> docopt(usage, argv='--test command')
{'--test': True,
 'another': False,
 'command': True}
```

Comment: @Roony, great! and thanks for you feedback, more of that is always welcome.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily add this argument to both parsers (main parser and subcommand parser):

```
import argparse                                                                  

main = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                                    
subparser = main.add_subparsers().add_parser('test')                                        

for p in [main,subparser]:                                                                  
   p.add_argument('--arg', action='store_true')                                 

print main.parse_args('--arg test'.split()).arg                                     
print main.parse_args('test --arg'.split()).arg
```

**Edit**: As @hpaulj pointed in comment, there is also `parents` argument which you can pass to `ArgumentParser` constructor or to `add_parser` method. You can list in this value parsers which are bases for new one.

```
import argparse

base = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
base.add_argument('--arg', action='store_true')

main = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[base])
subparser = main.add_subparsers().add_parser('test', parents=[base])

print main.parse_args('--arg test'.split()).arg
print main.parse_args('test --arg'.split()).arg
```

More examples/docs:

[looking for best way of giving command line arguments in python, where some params are req for some option and some params are req for other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328557/looking-for-best-way-of-giving-command-line-arguments-in-python-where-some-para/18346152#18346152)

[Python argparse - Add argument to multiple subparsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498595/python-argparse-add-argument-to-multiple-subparsers) (I'm not sure if this question is not overlaping with this one too much)

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#parents

Comment: If there were more optionals, they could be defined in a `parent` parser, and added to both `p` and `s` via the `parents` parameter.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18346152/901925 has an example of adding the same set of optionals to many subparsers.

Comment: @hpaulj - I think that this is even better answer! I'm going to update my response...

Comment: On Python 2.7.16, the second example prints `False` in the first case, which is, I believe, not at all the desired behavior?  Therefore I think the second, edited solution is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

There's a ton of argument-parsing libs in the Python world. Here are a few that I've seen, all of which should be able to handle address the problem you're trying to solve (based on my fuzzy recollection of them when I played with them last):

- [opster](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/opster)—I think this is what mercurial uses, IIRC
- [docopt](http://www.docopt.org/en/latest/index.html)—This one is new, but uses an interesting approach
- [cliff](http://readthedocs.org/docs/cliff/en/latest/)—This is a relatively new project by Doug Hellmann (PSF member, virtualenvwrapper author, general hacker extraordinaire) is a bit more than just an argument parser, but is designed from the ground up to handle multi-level commands
- [clint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/clint/)—Another project that aims to be "argument parsing and more", this one by Kenneth Reitz (of Requests fame).

Comment: Wow -- I didn't realize there were so many options -- I guess that's probably because I've always been able to coax argparse into submission.  +1 for finding all these though...

Comment: i did a quick investigation, docopt and clint wont do
cliff is a very strange and complex thing i dont want to have to understand
opster looks interesting, trying it

Comment: @Ronny, docopt should work—you can add `[options]` shortcut, it allows to pass global options regardless of sub-command hierarchy.

Comment: @Ronny i.e. case `'test --arg'` will be recognized in case you specify pattern `my_program test [options]` or `my_program test [--arg]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dirty workaround --

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--arg', action='store_true')
s = p.add_subparsers()
s.add_parser('test')

def my_parse_args(ss):
    #parse the info the subparser knows about; don't issue an error on unknown stuff
    namespace,leftover=p.parse_known_args(ss) 
    #reparse the unknown as global options and add it to the namespace.
    if(leftover):
        s.add_parser('null',add_help=False)
        p.parse_args(leftover+['null'],namespace=namespace)

    return namespace

#print my_parse_args('-h'.split())  #This works too, but causes the script to stop.
print my_parse_args('--arg test'.split())
print my_parse_args('test --arg'.split())
```

This works -- And you could modify it pretty easily to work with `sys.argv` (just remove the split string "`ss`").  You could even subclass `argparse.ArgumentParser` and replace the `parse_args` method with `my_parse_args` and then you'd never know the difference -- Although subclassing to replace a single method seems overkill to me.

I think however, that this is a lit bit of a non-standard way to use subparsers.  In general, global options are expected to come before subparser options, not after.

Answer (score 1):

The parser has a specific syntax: `command <global options> subcommand <subcommand ptions>`, you are trying to feed the subcommand with an option and but you didn't define one.

Comment: I think Ronny is aware of why it fails (or at least he doesn't care) -- he's looking for a workaround (using argparse or something else).