# argparse with required subcommands

Tags: python, argparse

With python's argparse, how do I make a subcommand a required argument? I want to do this because I want argparse to error out if a subcommand is not specified. I override the error method to print help instead. I have 3-deep nested subcommands, so it's not a matter of simply handling zero arguments at the top level.

In the following example, if this is called like so, I get:

```
$./simple.py
$
```

What I want it to do instead is for argparse to complain that the required subcommand was not specified:

```
import argparse

class MyArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        self.print_help(sys.stderr)
        self.exit(0, '%s: error: %s\n' % (self.prog, message))

def main():
    parser = MyArgumentParser(description='Simple example')
    subs = parser.add_subparsers()
    sub_one = subs.add_parser('one', help='does something')
    sub_two = subs.add_parser('two', help='does something else')

    parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There was a change in 3.3 in the error message for required arguments, and subcommands got lost in the dust.

http://bugs.python.org/issue9253#msg186387

There I suggest this work around, setting the `required` attribute after the `subparsers` is defined.

```
parser = ArgumentParser(prog='test')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
subparsers.required = True
subparsers.dest = 'command'
subparser = subparsers.add_parser("foo", help="run foo")
parser.parse_args()
```

### update

A related pull-request: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/3027

Comment: Excellent, that's what I needed. Works great now, and I'll watch out for the bug fix.

Answer (score 18):

In addition to [hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18283730/4137828): you can also use the `required` keyword argument with [`ArgumentParser.add_subparsers()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) since **Python 3.7**. You also need to pass `dest` as argument. Otherwise you will get an error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found`.

**Example** file `example.py`:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command', required=True)
foo_parser = subparsers.add_parser("foo", help="command foo")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

**Output** of the call without an argument:

```
$ python example.py
usage: example.py [-h] {foo} ...
example.py: error: the following arguments are required: command
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `required=True`? More info [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#required).

Comment: It isn't supported by the `add_subparsers()` method: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'`

Comment: We are adding this to Python 3.7, and making it the default behaviour.  Better late than never  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Did this make it into Python 3.7? It seems to be mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) however when I use it with 3.7.1 I get a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found` so maybe not.

Comment: Turns out you also need to provide a `dest` so that the subparser selection has a name: `parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", required=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dest` argument, which is documented in the last example in the documentation for [`add_subparsers()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers):

```
# required_subparser.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser_name')
one = subparsers.add_parser('one')
two = subparsers.add_parser('two')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Running with Python 2.7:

```
$python required_subparser.py 
usage: required_subparser.py [-h] {one,two} ...
required_subparser.py: error: too few arguments
$python required_subparser.py one
$# no error
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something here, but I don't get the "usage:" message when running your example. I get back to the prompt with no output with or without an argument. I'm using python 3.3.2 and the argparse that came along with it.

Comment: @redstreet You didn't mention you were using python3.3 and I tested it using the system `python` executable, which is python 2.7. Indeed with python3.3 you don't get the messages.

Comment: Yes, because I didn't expect this to be due to a bug (which made it dependent on the version!). Thank you for the answer and for trying it on 2.7!

Comment: using metavar in addition to dest helps make output make more sense