# Argparse with required subparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, argparse

I'm using Python 3.4, I'm trying to use `argparse` with subparsers, and I want to have a similar behavior to the one in Python 2.x where if I don't supply a positional argument (to indicate the subparser/subprogram) I'll get a helpful error message.  I.e., with `python2` I'll get the following error message:

```
$ python2 subparser_test.py    
usage: subparser_test.py [-h] {foo} ...
subparser_test.py: error: too few arguments
```

I'm setting the `required` attribute as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22994500/3061818, however that gives me an error with Python 3.4.0:  `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found` -  full traceback:

```
$ python3 subparser_test.py    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subparser_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1717, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1749, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1984, in _parse_known_args
    ', '.join(required_actions))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

This is my program `subparser_test.py` - adapted from https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands:

```
import argparse

# sub-command functions
def foo(args):
    print('"foo()" called')

# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
subparsers.required = True

# create the parser for the "foo" command
parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

Related question: [Why does this argparse code behave differently between Python 2 and 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22990977/3061818)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You need to give `subparsers` a `dest`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
subparsers.required = True
```

Now:

```
1909:~/mypy$ argdev/python3 stack23349349.py
usage: stack23349349.py [-h] {foo} ...
stack23349349.py: error: the following arguments are required: cmd
```

In order to issue this 'missing arguments' error message, the code needs to give that argument a name.  For a positional argument (like subparses), that name is (by default) the 'dest'.  There's a (minor) note about this in the SO answer you linked.

One of the few 'patches' to `argparse` in the last Python release changed how it tests for 'required' arguments.  Unfortunately it introduced this bug regarding subparsers.  This needs to be fixed in the next release (if not sooner).

### update

If you want this optional subparsers behavior in Py2, it looks like the best option is to use a two stage parser as described in

[How to Set a Default Subparser using Argparse Module with Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667843/how-to-set-a-default-subparser-using-argparse-module-with-python-2-7)

There has been some recent activity in the related bug/issue

https://bugs.python.org/issue9253

### update

A fix to this is in the works: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/3027

Comment: More information about the argparse bug [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18283730/406776). Upvoting that answer seems to help raise its urgency in the Python bug queue. [Really, I'm not just farming rep for someone!](https://bugs.python.org/issue9253#msg267692)

Comment: Update: the fix has been reverted for "compatibility" reasons: https://bugs.python.org/issue33109  -- guess this bug will live on forever

Comment: Since Python 3.7 `required` can be used as argument: `parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', required=True)`, [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers)

Comment: the dest parameter is no longer required, only required is :p. As in, you can just specify `parser.add_subparsers(required=True)` if you don't want to give it a named destination.

Comment: @Moodragonx that gives an incomprehensible error message if the argument is missing.

Comment: @Elazar `parser.add_subparsers(metavar='command', required=True)` works well, the help is OK... tested with python 3.10.5 and 3.6.8 (`required=True` must be `subparsers.required = True` in 3.6).

Comment: The issue with all of these solutions is the help of the original parser is lost and not printed!

Answer (score 0):

The previous mentioned workaround is no longer required as the `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` method also accepts a required argument.

This will indicate that least one of the mutually exclusive arguments is required.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

group.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')

> parser.parse_args([])
> usage: PROG [-h] (--foo | --bar)
> PROG: error: one of the arguments --foo --bar is required
```

Taken from the argsparse docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group