# Add some argument if and only if the parser has not any subparsers

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

The commandline interface that I want is something like this:

```
my-executable command REQUIRED_ARG
# or
my-executable command subcommand [--foo] [--bar]
```

So, I don't want `REQUIRED_ARG` to be required (and to be parsed) when the `subcommand` exists.

Mutually exclusive group is close to what I want, but I cannot add subparsers to it. Another approach was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998417/create-parser-with-subcommands-in-argparse-customize-positional-arguments) but that's not my case: I want `REQUIRED_ARG` not to be parsed at all in case of subcommand (and this also seems to be a hack).

Comment: Both `REQUIRED_ARG` and `subcommand` are positionals.  Values are allocated to positionals based on position, not value.  If a string is not in the subparsers list of `choices` it raises an error.

Comment: @hpaulj But `subcommand` is not positional argument, it's subparser.

Comment: To the main parser, a `subparser` is just a `positional` with a special `action` `_SubParsersAction`.  The subparsers are `choices`.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands.

Comment: Due to a change in how `argparse` tests for required arguments, subparsers are now optional, at least in PY3.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349349/argparse-with-required-subparser.  Any ways I think the linked answer is still relevant to this issue.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by `not to be parsed at all`.  Do you mean don't complain if it's missing?  Or ignore the string even if present?  In `argparse` parsing is controlled by flags (e.g. '--foo') and by position.  They aren't parsed conditionally based on their own value or value type, or value of other strings.

Comment: Another option is to parse the input a couple of times, once to identify some usage case (e.g. check `sys.argv[1]` for certain values), and again to parse that special situation.  Ultimately the `argparse` parser is just a tool for figuring out what your user wants.  It's not your whole program.