# Python argparse: args has no attribute func

Tags: python

### Intro

I'm trouble for a school project. I'm making a testsuit and i'm needing bot a configuration generation interface and a test runner. For that i used the library `argparse` and two subparsers `cgi` and `run`

### The issue itself

So here is the failing code section:

```
def CGI(args):
    print("CGI: Work In Progress")
    exit(0)


def runTest(args):
    print("Run: Work in Progress")
    exit(0)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparser = parser.add_subparsers()
cgi = subparser.add_parser("cgi", help="CSV Generator Interface")
run = subparser.add_parser("run", help="Test running")
verbosity = parser.add_argument_group("Verbosity").add_mutually_exclusive_group()
check = run.add_argument_group("Checks")

# Arguments
#Run parser
run.set_defaults(func=runTest)

# Run argument declaration ...

# Verbosity argument declaration ...

# Check argument declaration ...

#CGI
cgi.set_defaults(func=CGI)

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args) # Error is here
```

Whenever i run this code i have the following error:

```
  File "/home/thor/Projects/EPITA/TC/test/test.py", line 44, in main
    args.func(args)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'func'
```

### Python version

```
$ python -V
Python 3.6.4
```

### Argparse version

```
$ pip show argparse
Name: argparse
Version: 1.4.0
Summary: Python command-line parsing library
Home-page: https://github.com/ThomasWaldmann/argparse/
Author: Thomas Waldmann
Author-email: tw@waldmann-edv.de
License: Python Software Foundation License
Location: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

### EDIT

If i install argparse manually it work `sudo pip install argparse`. But is there any native solution. I'm not sure it will work on school's computers (we can' install packages)

### EDIT 2

OK my bad i've been a total idiot i didn't rewrited my running script so i forgot to input `run` or `cgi`

Thanks for reading my message and for your future help :)

Comment: Yep, exactly. You learned the hard way that subparsers (including their defaults) are only run when their respective command is present in the arguments. Note that you can answer your own questions.

Comment: The recommended solution is `p1 = parser.add_subparsers(required=True, dest='cmd')` See https://bugs.python.org/issue16308#msg350415

Comment: Just to add to above comment, as mentioned by "makeiteasy" below Python version 3.6 onwards 'required' has to be used explicitly:

subparser.required = True

Answer (score 17):

This is a known bug in the Python 3 version of argparse (https://bugs.python.org/issue16308). In Python 2, if the script is called with no arguments whatsoever (i.e., no subcommand), it exits cleanly with "error: too few arguments". In Python3, however, you get an unhandled `AttributeError`. Luckily, the workaround is pretty straightforward:

```
    try:
        func = args.func
    except AttributeError:
        parser.error("too few arguments")
    func(args)
```

Answer (score 17):

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.set_defaults(func=lambda args: parser.print_help())
```

imho better than try..except

Comment: This is expressive (it tells you what it does) and does exactly what you want. Only thing I'd say is that you can replace `func=lambda args:` with `func=lambda _:` because `args` isn't used.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to make subparsers required to call the script without arguments. To do that, you have to specify the `dest` and `required` arguments for the `parser.add_subparsers`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', required=True)
```

Note that for Python 3.6 and earlier there's no `required` argument and you have to set it explicitly for the `subparser` object:

```
subparser.required = True
```

Details are available in this SO answer: [Argparse with required subparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349349/argparse-with-required-subparser/23354355#23354355)

Comment: For anyone reading this answer (which is the official answer according to https://bugs.python.org/issue16308#msg350415 and should therefore be upvoted),
I suggest adding also `metavar='cmd'` to `add_subparsers`.

Without metavar: `usage: jobs.py [-h] {run,list,show}`.
With metavar: `usage: jobs.py [-h] cmd`.

As the error message when no cmd is provided is "error: the following arguments are required: cmd", I prefer to have `cmd` explicitly displayed in usage.

The available choices for `cmd` are displayed in the full help anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be:

```
if len(args.__dict__) <= 1:
    # No arguments or subcommands were given.
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, a combination of @simleo and @nehaljwani's answers:

```
    # Parse the arguments and call the sub command
    args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        args.func(args)
    except AttributeError:
        parser.print_help()
        parser.exit()
```

Comment: exactly, was going to post the same, but without passing args to func, just args.func inside the try

Answer (score 1):

This error only happened when you run 'python script.py' directly.
'python script.py --help' works fine.

Add

```
args = parser.parse_args()
try:
    args.func(args)
except AttributeError:
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit()
```

will help you handle this case of running 'python script.py' directly.
It resolved my issue, thanks very much!