# argparse with optional subcommands not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Using python version 3.9.5 I have a problem with the following code snippet:

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(required=False)
sub_parser = subparsers.add_parser("sub")

parser.add_argument("global-argument")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Running the python example without arguments, results into the following error message:

```
$ python3 main.py
usage: main.py [-h] {sub} ... global-argument
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: global-argument
```

The error message shows that only the global-argument is required and the subcommand is optional.

But running the python example with the global argument, results into the following error message:

```
$ python3 main.py global
usage: main.py [-h] {sub} ... global-argument
main.py: error: invalid choice: 'global' (choose from 'sub')
```

So it's impossible to provide the global-argument without the subcommand (which should be optional)?

Comment: Good find! Seems to me like a bug/design decision in `argparse`. What should be the logic if you say want provide `global-argument` with value `sub` - how do you tell `argparse` that it is global positional argument and not valid sub-parser command name? I'd expect them to support `--` but that doesn't work either. Best to ask in Python bug tracker. It should be at least documented (which is not) if intended.

Comment: @blami, as a general rule, main parser arguments should all be defined before creating the `subparsers`.  You can get away with adding an `optional` after, but not another `positional`.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `parser`. `subparsers` is a `positional` argument, as is `global-argument`.  `positionals` are parsed in the order they are defined.  But since parsing is passed to the subparser when it's encountered, and not passed back to main, 'global-argument' can be handled in any case.

An `optional` could be defined for `parser` after, but that's because `optionals` are handled in to order that the user provides them.

To `parser`. `subparsers` is just a specialized kind of `positional`, one that passes the parsing task on to another parser.  `sub_parser` when invoked handles the remaining strings, and returns a `namespace` which is incorporated in the main `namespace`.  `parser` does not resume parsing.

So the main parser's arguments should all be defined first, and used in the command line first.  The `subparser(s)` and arguments are defined and used after that.

Originally `subparsers` was not optional, as is normal for `positionals` (without special `nargs`).  But as an unintended side effect of changing how 'required' arguments are tested and flagged, `subparsers` became, by default, not-required.  We've been dealing with the fall out from that for a while.

My top voted answer deals with this; [Argparse with required subparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349349/argparse-with-required-subparser)

Also it's a good idea to include a `dest`, both to better identify which subparser was used, and to prevent problems in the error message.

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
```

Comment: first sorry for contacting you this way. I admire your numpy skills. I am trying to learn it. Any good tutorial, courses you know of?

Comment: @wwnde, I haven't looked at tutorials.  Usually I just encourage people to read the basic docs, e.g. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html.  It's hard to separate what I learned from the original 2006 book, https://web.mit.edu/dvp/Public/numpybook.pdf, and what I've picked up from use and SO.

Comment: nice one, I will certainly look into the docs as advised. Many thanks