# Argparse: options for subparsers override main if both share parent

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm using argparse with several subparsers. I want my program to take options for verbosity anywhere in the args, including the subparser.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--verbose', '-v', action='count')

sub = p.add_subparsers()
a = sub.add_parser('a')

print(p.parse_args())
```

By default, options for the main parser will throw an error if used for subparsers:

```
$ python tmp.py -v a
Namespace(verbose=1)

$ python tmp.py a -v
usage: tmp.py [-h] [--verbose] {a} ...
tmp.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -v
```

I looked into parent parsers, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7498853).

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parent = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent.add_argument('--verbose', '-v', action='count')

main = ArgumentParser(parents=[parent])

sub = main.add_subparsers()
a = sub.add_parser('a', parents=[parent])

print(main.parse_args())
```

For some reason though, none of the shared flags work on the main parser.

```
$ python tmp2.py a -vvv
Namespace(verbose=3)
$ python tmp2.py -vvv a
Namespace(verbose=None)
```

Note that the main parser definitely has the appropriate arguments, because when I change it to `main = ArgumentParser()` I get `error: unrecognized arguments: -v`. What am I missing here?

Comment: You could add `argument_default=SUPPRESS` to the parent parser, but that just prevents the subparser from applying its default if the subparser doesn't use `-v` at all. Otherwise, the subparser still overrides anything does by the main parser, rather than augmenting it.

Comment: I think the answer is to define a `SharedCountAction` rather than using the builtin `_CountAction` (specified by `action='count')`, but I am not sure what that definition would look like.

Comment: I looked at [`_CountAction`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L995) and it look about right. I think the problem is in [`_SubParsersAction.__call__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L1149), which overwrites any existing attributes with that of the subparser.

Comment: this seems to support that: if the script is called without subparsers, it works fine: `$ python tmp2.py -v` gives `Namespace(verbose=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a couple of general comments.

The main parser handles the input upto the subparser invocation, then the subparser is called and given the remaining `argv`.  When it is done, it's `namespace` is merged back into the the main `namespace`.

The `parents` mechanism copies Actions from the `parent` by reference.  So your main and subparsers share the same `verbose` Action object.  That's been a problem when the subparser tries to set a different default or help.  It may not be an issue here, but just keep it in mind.

Even without the `parents` mechanism, sharing a `dest` or options flag between main and subparser can be tricky.  Should the default of the subparser Action be used?  What if both are used?  Does the subparser overwrite the main parser's actions?

Originally the main `namespace` was passed to the subparser, which it modified and returned.  This was changed a while back (I can find the bug/issue if needed).  Now the subparser starts with a default empty `namespace`, fills it.  And these values are then merged into the main.

So in your linked SO question, be wary of older answers. `argparse` may have changed since then.

I think what's happening in your case is that the main and subparser `verbose` are counting separately.  And when you get `None` it's the subparser's default that you see.

The `__call__` for `_Count_Action` is:

```
def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    new_count = _ensure_value(namespace, self.dest, 0) + 1
    setattr(namespace, self.dest, new_count)
```

I suspect that in older `argparse` when the namespace was shared, the `count` would have been cumulative, but I can't test it without recreating an older style `subparser` action class.

https://bugs.python.org/issue15327 - here the original developer suggests giving the two arguments different `dest`.  That records the inputs from both main and sub.  Your own code can then merge the results if needed.

https://bugs.python.org/issue27859 `argparse - subparsers does not retain namespace`.  Here I suggest a way of recreating the older style.

https://bugs.python.org/issue9351 `argparse set_defaults on subcommands should override top level set_defaults` - this is the issue in 2014 that changed the namespace use.

Comment: This is interesting, but it doesn't answer my question. You mentioned that `your main and subparsers share the same verbose Action object`. This is good, that's what I want to happen and what I would expect. Since both of these use 'count', I would expect the effect to be additive, i.e. `myprog -v a -v` should have a verbose count of 2.

Comment: Actually the `count` is done in the `namespace`.  It is done by the `Action`, but it doesn't modify its own values.  I added the `__call__` code.

Comment: `argparse` has been pretty stable, but it probably wasn't designed to handle this use case.

Comment: I wrote this above - I think the problem is in [`_Subparser.__call__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L1149), the parent value is being overridden by the subparser value. Would it be appropriate to file a bug report for this? Or is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: ~~actually while I'm at it, I have python2.7 installed, let me see if the behaviour is the same~~ behavior is the same in 2.7.14 as 3.6.2

Comment: I like your idea of different `dest` for each and then adding. I think that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 1):

I found a robust workaround for this issue, both for `store_true` and `count`. It leverages the `default` value for the action, therefore it may collide with more complex usages (but works just fine for the OP use case):

1. For the `store_true` case:

   ```python
   class StoreTrueAction(argparse._StoreTrueAction):
       def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
           self.default = self.const
           setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.const)
   ```

   To replace the `store_false`, simply inherit from `argparse._StoreFalseAction` instead.
2. For the `count` case:

   ```python
       class CountAction(argparse._CountAction):
       def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
           count = getattr(namespace, self.dest, None)
           if count is None:
               count = 0

           if not self.default:
               self.default = count + 1
           else:
               self.default += count

           setattr(namespace, self.dest, count + 1)
   ```

### Example usage:

```python
# test.py
import argparse

class StoreTrueAction(argparse._StoreTrueAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        self.default = self.const
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.const)


class CountAction(argparse._CountAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        count = getattr(namespace, self.dest, None)
        if count is None:
            count = 0

        if not self.default:
            self.default = count + 1
        else:
            self.default += count

        setattr(namespace, self.dest, count + 1)


parent = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action=CountAction)
parent.add_argument("-f", "--force", action=StoreTrueAction)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parent])
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_a = subparsers.add_parser("a", parents=[parent])
parser_a.set_defaults(cmd="a")

print(parser.parse_args())
```

Outputs:

```python
$ python test.py -vv 
Namespace(verbose=2, force=False)
$ python test.py -vv -f
Namespace(verbose=2, force=True)
$ python test.py -vv -f a
Namespace(verbose=2, force=True, cmd='a')
$ python test.py a -vv -f 
Namespace(verbose=2, force=True, cmd='a')
$ python test.py -vv -f a -vv -f
Namespace(verbose=4, force=True, cmd='a')
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this behavior, which is very well described in @hpaulj's answer is to create a second parser that does not have subparsers but only the positional arguments that were first found.

The first parse_args, used with the first parser, will validate the positional arguments and flags, show an error message if needed or show the proper help.

The second parse_args, for the second parser, will correctly fill in the namespace.

Building on your example:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parent = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent.add_argument('--verbose', '-v', action='count')

main1 = ArgumentParser(parents=[parent])
sub = main1.add_subparsers()

# eg: tmp.py -vv a -v
a = sub.add_parser('a', parents=[parent])
a.set_defaults(which='a')

# eg: tmp.py -vv v -v --output toto
b = sub.add_parser('b', parents=[parent])
b.add_argument('--output', type=str)
b.set_defaults(which='b')

args = main1.parse_args()
print(args)

# parse a second time with another parser
main2 = ArgumentParser(parents=[parent])
if args.which == 'a':
    main2.add_argument('a')
elif args.which == 'b':
    main2.add_argument('b')
    main2.add_argument('--output', type=str)

print(main2.parse_args())
```

Which gives:

```
$ ./tmp.py -vv a -v

Namespace(verbose=1, which='a')
Namespace(a='a', verbose=3)

$ ./tmp.py -vv b -v --output toto
Namespace(output='toto', verbose=1, which='b')
Namespace(b='b', output='toto', verbose=3)

$ ./tmp.py  -vv a  --output
usage: tmp.py [-h] [--verbose] {a,b} ...
tmp.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --output
```

I use this technique with multiple nested subparsers.