# Writing commands and flags separate with argparse

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I was writing down a code in python which makes use of argparse module to make it easier to use it.

I can add arguments in the form of **flags** like:

```
parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', dest='url', help='type in url')
```

But like in gobuster, when you use help flag (-h) you can see you can also pass **commands** like dir,fuzz,etc. They also have separate help flags for each of them like

```
gobuster dir --help
```

how to achieve this? I can make flags without arguments by:

```
parser.add_argument('R', action='store_true', help='allow recursion')
```

In short, I'm trying to find out how to define **commands** separately so that they also show up under *commands* in help section and not under *optional arguments*. I'm also trying to find out how to create a separate help section for each command.

Comment: Does the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) help?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I looked through official page, but unfortunately I could not find the solution there.

Comment: If I get what you want - have a look at [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/commands/). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/59391084/4046632

Comment: Also with argparse - check https://stackoverflow.com/q/7498595/4046632

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands is one option.  Another could be `argument_groups`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-groups.  Groups affect help display only, not parsing.  "optional arguments" is just one default argument_group.  You can make more with your own choice of names.

Comment: @buran, I suspect that link is to a more complicated subparsers usage than this user needs.

Comment: @hpaulj, I agree. But the fact is we all guess and it is not very clear what they really want.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add it via subparsers with separate help message and parent arguments.

```
 arg_parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 1.0')
 subparsers = arg_parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands',dest='subcommandsarg',help='Program parser for subcommands')
 parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
 parser1.add_argument('-a','--arg1', dest='module',required=False,help='Mod Name' ,default='all')
 subparsers.add_parser('parser1',parents=[parser1],help="Help text for parser1")
 parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
 parser2.add_argument('-b','--arg2', dest='module',required=False,help='Mod Name' ,default='all')
 subparsers.add_parser('parser2',parents=[parser2],help="Gets the configuration of mods")
 options = arg_parser.parse_args()
```

## output

```
#python test.py -h
usage: program [-h] [--version] {parser1,parser2} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --version          show program's version number and exit

subcommands:
  {parser1,parser2}  Program parser for subcommands
    parser1          Help text for parser1
    parser2          Gets the configuration of mods

#python test.py parser1 -h
usage: program parser1 [-h] [-a MODULE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a MODULE, --arg1 MODULE
                        Mod Name

#python test.py parser2 -h
usage: program parser2 [-h] [-b MODULE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -b MODULE, --arg2 MODULE
                        Mod Name
```