# Select limited arguments from Parent Parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, argparse, subparsers

I have been working with Argparse for a while and here's the [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7498853/9822716) to the question that I was having.

> [Add arguments to multiple subparsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7498595/9822716)

This answer is not completely solving my problem.

Here's the edited code borrowed from the answer.
(I have added a comment before adding the newline)

```
import argparse

parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="The parent parser")
parent_parser.add_argument("-p", type=int, required=True,
                           help="set db parameter")

#adding a new parent argument
parent_parser.add_argument("-q", type=int, required=True,
                           help="help with -q")


subparsers = parent_parser.add_subparsers(title="actions")
parser_create = subparsers.add_parser("create", parents=[parent_parser],
                                      add_help=False,
                                      description="The create parser",
                                      help="create the orbix environment")
parser_create.add_argument("--name", help="name of the environment")
parser_update = subparsers.add_parser("update", parents=[parent_parser],
                                      add_help=False,
                                      description="The update parser",
                                      help="update the orbix environment")
```

The edited code represents this

- -p & -q as the Parent Arguments

The problem is, I dont want to use that the new Parent Argument '-q' in my subparser.

I just want to use the argument '-p' in any of the subparsers.

It sounds a little different, but as I'm dealing with so many subparsers, I really want the best option for my subparsers.

What should I do for that?

Comment: The accepted answer in your linked SO is old and problematic.  The newer answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you can add arguments to the parent parser after having created subparsers. So you can do like this :

```
import argparse

parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="The parent parser")
parent_parser.add_argument("-p", type=int, required=True,
                           help="set db parameter")

# Not adding now


subparsers = parent_parser.add_subparsers(title="actions")
parser_create = subparsers.add_parser("create", parents=[parent_parser],
                                      add_help=False,
                                      description="The create parser",
                                      help="create the orbix environment")
parser_create.add_argument("--name", help="name of the environment")
parser_update = subparsers.add_parser("update", parents=[parent_parser],
                                      add_help=False,
                                      description="The update parser",
                                      help="update the orbix environment")

#adding a new parent argument
parent_parser.add_argument("-q", type=int, required=True,
                           help="help with -q")
```

You then have the following helps :

#### For the parent parser

```
>>> parent_parser.print_help()
usage: temp.py [-h] -p P -q Q {create,update} ...

The parent parser

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -p P             set db parameter
  -q Q             help with -q

actions:
  {create,update}
    create         create the orbix environment
    update         update the orbix environment
```

#### For the subparsers

```
>>> parser_create.print_help()
usage: temp.py create [-h] -p P [--name NAME] {create,update} ...

The create parser

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -p P             set db parameter
  --name NAME      name of the environment
# no q here

actions:
  {create,update}
    create         create the orbix environment
    update         update the orbix environment

>>> parser_update.print_help()
usage: temp.py update [-h] -p P {create,update} ...

The update parser

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -p P             set db parameter
# no -q here neither
actions:
  {create,update}
    create         create the orbix environment
    update         update the orbix environment
```

Is that the result you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Some points that are apparent in past SO questions about `parent` and `subparsers`.

- don't define the same arguments (`dest`) in the main and subparsers
- as a consequence, don't use the main parser as a parent.
- you can define and pass multiple parsers in the `parents` list.
- `parents` is just a convenience tool.  Don't use it if it gives you problems (or you don't understand it).
- it's easy to write your own utility function(s) to add arguments to subparsers.  These will be easier to customize.
- `argparse` is a python module, defining python classes.  Use basic python thinking where useful.