# How to define a multi-level and conditional command-line ArgumentParser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I have a python project with multiple scripts. The structure is organized as:

```
project-folder
   ...
   src
      scripts
         script1
         script2
   __main__.py
```

I want to execute the scripts at `project-folder` level, where you can invoke the script you wanna execute as `python -script1` or `python -script2`. If you specify `script1`, then you are allowed to provide all relevant command-line arguments for `script1`, i.e. `python -script1 -script1param1="..." -script1param2="..."`, etc. For `script2` applies the same: `python -script2 -script2param1="..." -script2param2="..."`.

I could define at script level script specific cmd options, like `python -script1param1="..." -script1param2="..."` or `python -script2param1="..." -script2param2="..."`, and at `project-folder` level the option which script you want to run, either `python -script1` or `python -script2`, but I couldn't combine both in one.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it

(Thanks to [Conditional command line arguments in Python using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505898/conditional-command-line-arguments-in-python-using-argparse) and [Select limited arguments from Parent Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861708/select-limited-arguments-from-parent-parser))

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Run one of the following scripts.\n"
                "- 1: python . script1 -script1param1='...' -script1param2='...'\n"
                "- 2: python . script2 -script2param1='...' -script2param2='...'",
    formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter
)

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(
    dest='action',
    help="Adds script specific command line arguments.")

script1_parser = script1.get_parser()
script1_parser = subparsers.add_parser("script1",
                                     parents=[script1_parser],
                                     add_help=False,
                                     help="Runs script 1.")
script2_parser = script2.get_parser()
script2_parser = subparsers.add_parser("script2",
                                     parents=[script2_parser],
                                     add_help=False,
                                     help="Runs script 2.")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.action == 'script1':
    script1.main(args)
elif args.action == 'script2':
    script2.main(args)
```

So the key elements here are actually:

1. the `subparsers` where we can attach a 'branch' parser based on `action` value (script1 or 2); and
2. the `parents` parameter of `add_parser`. In each script we define its args parser, get the parser by `script.get_parser()`, and pass it to `add_parser` in `parents`.