# Argparser's one subparser for two different commands

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I have this three types of commands in code:

```
test.py save file_name
test.py load file_name
test.py list_files
```

Currently, to parse them i use three subparsers, but is there opportunity to use one subparser to two commads 'load' and 'save', because they use same argument 'file_name'?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test parser')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')

parser_load = subparsers.add_parser("load")
parser_load.add_argument("file_name")

parser_save = subparsers.add_parser("save")
parser_save.add_argument("file_name")

parser_list_files = subparsers.add_parser("list_files")
```

Comment: I've never done this myself, but I found this question after a quick search and it looks promising: [Add argument to multiple subparsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7498595/4518341)

Comment: What's wrong with the code you show?  You've already done the hard work of typing both cases :)  But you could try making `save` an alias for `load`.   I think the alias will appear as the `command` value (but check).

Answer (score 0):

If the two commands are identical, they can be aliases of the same parser

```
In [6]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [7]: sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
In [8]: sp1 = sp.add_parser('load', aliases=['store'])
In [9]: sp1.add_argument('test');

In [10]: parser.parse_args('load foo'.split())
Out[10]: Namespace(cmd='load', test='foo')

In [12]: parser.parse_args('store foo'.split())
Out[12]: Namespace(cmd='store', test='foo')
```

The alias appears in the namespace.

```
In [13]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] {load,store} ...

positional arguments:
  {load,store}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
```

But if you prefer to keep them separate, there are various ways to ease your typing burden.

- There's copy-n-paste
- There's the `parents` mechanism, cute but limited.
- Or use one or more utility functions to create multiple subparsers.

The Perl inventor claimed programmers are lazy, going to great lengths to avoid typing repetitive code.   http://threevirtues.com/